# Native Target Data

Tags: llvm, doxygen

In the doxygen reference manual for llvm you can create a target data instance from a Module object or execution engine.

How do I get the target data for the current/native platform?

Answer (score 0):

Well... usually the information to be added to TargetData can be extracted from the platform ABI document. This is where all natural sizes, alignments, etc. are specified. Sometimes if you have a compiler for your platform you can try to match all entries with your compiler.

I believe in the latter case it is possible to write some binary which will generate the TargetData info for you but noone did this before iirc.

Comment: It sounds like what your are describing is a per-platform solution. I would like somthing that will port to any platform. I noticed that calling the TargetData constructor with an empty string works. Can anyone confirm that this is correct?

Comment: @sean, While empty / no TargetData will certainly work, it will inhibit many important optimizations. Also, in order to generate the binary code the TargetData should be non-empty. The backend will "fix" this problem for you :)